# Implement a simple HTTP DDOS protection in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, ddos

I want to implement a simple HTTP Denial-of-Service protection.
There are clients that can send HTTP request to a Server (i.e. a GET Method of http://10.1.1.2:8080/?clientId=7)

if in an interval of 10 seconds more then 10 request comes from a specific client the 11th, 12th.. requests will get blocked. until 10 seconds from the first request will pass and then a new time windows of 10 seconds will be open. the idea is   no more than 10 requests per 10 secs.

The time frame starts on each client’s first request and ends 10 seconds later.

I want to implement this logic on the server.
Which data  structures/collection/custom made object would you build to implement such a logic...

it is also important to have a threats safe solution.. and performances is also a factor here..

Thanks.

Comment: This is called request throttling. It's implemented in the API gateways already, have a look at https://konghq.com/kong-community-edition/